# Remove Title, Editor and Meta Box Support Based on Post Formats

Tags: metabox, editor, title, post-formats

Been looking around and can't find this.  Is it possible to remove, let's say, the title area on post format: "quote"?

Or the editor on post format: "image"?

I noticed this page in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Seems you could pull it off if you created a custom post type for images, for example, then removed support for that type, but that defeats the purpose of formats and also would break new themes, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about the format setting which was introduced in WP 3.1 for the `posts` post type? No, I don't think this is possible.

To remove the title-, editor- or any other metabox, you have to remove the `support` for this feature from the current `post type`. (e.g. remove the feature from the `supports` parameter inside `register_post_type()` or during execution with `remove_post_type_support()`).

This will affect the hole post type `posts`. You cannot limit this behavior by the post formats property. This isn't a post type, it's just a post meta for the post type `posts`.

What you could do is to hide the boxes based on the post formats value with jQuery. But this only works if the user has enabled JavaScript. It's also more a hack than a solution.